# What OTA updates did my S5active att gophone get 12-20-16?

Tags: updates

I received am update yesterday day and it behaved as if it was a security patch. or even an OS update. but obviously it wasn't that. but I can't really notice too much of a change on my phone except FB gas some new features. (w/o fb update) and my about phone info says November sucurity patch?? did I just get that late? was it a marshmallow bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great question for AT&T, since they would've approved for a device update.  Did you contact them at all to ask about this?  Looking at their site [here](https://www.att.com/devicehowto/tutorial.html#!/stepbystep/id/stepbystep_KM1126238?make=Samsung&model=GalaxyS5ActiveG870A):

```
Release date: December 19, 2016    
Android version: 6.0.1    
Security patch level (SPL): November 1, 2016    
Baseband version: G870AUCU2DPK2    
Kernel version: 3.4.0-9723602    
Build number: MMB29M.G870AUCU2DPK2    
File size: 164MB    
What's new: Android device security updates    
What's changing: Call and data reliability improvements for certain network conditions
```